# Given $M= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{array} } \right]$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f_M(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For $M=   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}    a & b \\    c & d \\   \end{array} } \right]$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f_M(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Let $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})=\{M:\det M=1\}$ and $I_{2}$ be the $2\times2$ identity matrix.Prove that if $M,M'$ are two $2\times2$ matrices with real entries then $f_{MM'}(z)=f_{M}(f_{M'}(z))$.Also, prove that the map $\Gamma(M)=f_{M}$ is a group homomorphism from $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ to $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ and find its kernel. Use this to prove that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ as a group is isomorphic to $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\{\pm I_{2}\}$ (where the latter is a quotient group.) You may assume that as a set $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})=\{f_{M}:M\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\}$

I tried to find many different sources to help me solve this but I'm honestly clueless. Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you get for $f_{MM'}(z)$ and $f_{M}(f_{M'}(z))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is simple to prove that
$$f_{MM'}=f_{M}\circ f_{M'}$$
just by tedious algebra and simplifications, which I will leave to you. To prove that $\Gamma: SL(2,\mathbb{R})\to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{H}): M\mapsto f_M$ is a homeomorphism we need to show it sends the identity to the identity and that it respects group operations. From the above we see that
$$\Gamma(MM')=f_{MM'}=f_M\circ f_{M'}=\Gamma(M)\circ \Gamma(M').$$
To show it maps the identity to the identity we simply have
$$\Gamma\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\frac{1\cdot z+0}{0\cdot z+1}=z.$$
To check the kernel we look for which $M$ we have that $\Gamma(M)=z$. Since
$$\Gamma\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)=\frac{a z+b}{c z+d}$$
we are looking for when
$$\frac{a z+b}{c z+d}=z.$$
This is the same as $az+b=cz^2+dz$. For these polynomials to be the same, their coefficients must match, so $c=0$, $d=a$ and $b=0$. Thus $\Gamma(M)=z$ iff $M=aI$. Since $\det(aI)=a^2$, $aI\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ iff $a=\pm 1$. Thus $\ker(\Gamma)=\pm I_2$. The fact that
$$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})\cong SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\ker(\Gamma)=SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\{\pm I_2\}$$
then follows.

Comment: With what theorem do we know $$\hbox{Aut}(\mathbb{H})\cong SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\ker(/Gamma)$$?

Comment: It’s the first isomorphism theorem using the assumption we’re given that $\text{Im}(\Gamma)=\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$.